# New activity when click on ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I treat XML and deduce which category parent_id = 0. Each line in the list has a unique id. How to display the list of strings that Activity belong to this line? (eg string has id = 1. When you click on this line you want to display a string in which the parent_id = 1). Need to use the new Activity or can use CatalogActivity.java?

**CatalogActivity.java**

```
public class CatalogActivity extends ListActivity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
static final String URL = "https://api.api2cart.com/v1.0/category.list.xml?api_key=6aed775211e8c3d556db063d12125d2d&store_key=ed58a22dfecb405a50ea3ea56979360d&start=0&count=38&params=id,name,parent_id,images";

    static final String KEY_ITEM = "category";
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_PARENT_ID = "parent_id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "name";<br>
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "http_path";
    String Parend_id;
    int id_parent;
    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> catalogList;

    //@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        catalogList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        new LoadCatalog().execute();
    }

        class LoadCatalog extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>   {

             @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CatalogActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Загрузка каталога ...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    pDialog.show();
                }

             protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                 XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
                    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

                    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                    // looping through all song nodes &lt;song&gt;

                    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

                        // creating new HashMap
                        //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                        Parend_id=parser.getValue(e, KEY_PARENT_ID);                        
                        if(Parend_id.equals("0")) { 
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID)); 
                            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL)); 
                            catalogList.add(map); 
                            }


                    }
                    return null;

             }


             protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    // updating UI from Background Thread
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            list=getListView();
                            adapter=new LazyAdapter(CatalogActivity.this, catalogList);
                            list.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    });


       // list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id,list);


        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList


        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent showInfo = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CatalogActivity.class);
                startActivity(showInfo);

            }
        });
    }

}
}
```

[example XML file](http://s017.radikal.ru/i438/1312/93/17c7c4df5bcf.png) (XML rendered as a PNG)

When I click on Components in ListView put Mac as id Components = parent_id Mac

Comment: you want to open detail activity when user clicks on any list item?

Comment: Yes. Clicking on any item in the list you want to display its sub-categories